# Spring mvc calling controller from jsp results in wrong url

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new in developing with Spring MVC. 
I am trying to call the controller from my jsp file.
I gave the requestmapping annotation to the controller, but when I try to call from my mainview.jsp which is found on the url: (I am testing on localhost) "/AirlineDB_Spring/views/mainview.jsp" (this works fine),
the project name disappears from the url and I get this address which gives me 404: "/passengers/" I don't know why "AirlineDB_Spring/" disappears from the link, this looks like the main problem.

My Controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/passengers")
public class PassengerController{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {
        List<String> tl = new ArrayList<String>();
        tl.add("one");
        tl.add("two");
        tl.add("three");
        model.addAttribute("testlist", tl);
        return "mainview";
    }
```

My jsp file's code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Airline Database</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h2>Passengers</h2>
     <a href="/passengers/">click</a>
     <c:forEach items="${model.testlist}" var="test" varStatus="loopStatus">
         ${loopStatus.count}  ${test}<br/>
     </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml file:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>airlinedb</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>airlinedb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

THe servlet-context.xml contains this:

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="airlinedb.controller"/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I searched through the internet, found a lot of problems in connection with controller mapping, but none of those worked for me, I also tried calling the controller with href="/passenger" but got the same 404.
I don't know what configs I am missing, I can see that I get the wrong url, but I have no idea what might be wrong.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is you view resolver?

Comment: I think the problem comes from your jsp : have you tried to redirect to <c:url value="passengers" /> ?

Comment: the view resolver is in the servlet-context.xml:
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/views/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>

Comment: I tried your advice: <c:url value="passengers" /> the url seems fine now, but it's still a 404, I get the error that there's no mapping for this URI in DispatcherServlet, I used "/" shouldn't it be a general mapping, that i can use multiple types of urls?

Comment: It is, this message means there is no view associated with this address. Could you tell me the address where you get a 404 ?

Comment: I call the url: http://localhost:8080/AirlineDB_Spring/passengers that gives me a 404, it should be the Controller which redirects when done to the url I called it from: http://localhost:8080/AirlineDB_Spring/views/mainview.jsp

Comment: Just to be sure, have you kept the corrections proposed by Sridhar ? If so, please update the code in your post.

Comment: yes I did keep them, I used the first one

Comment: Does `localhost:8080/AirlineDB_Spring/passengers/` gives you a 404 too ?

Comment: yes, I tried with and without the / at the end

Comment: This might happend because your servlet doesn't read the config file.
Try adding   `<init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>` in in your `web.xml` in the servlet declaration.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! changing *.xml to servlet-context.xml actually helped, I still have problem with getting the information from the model, but now i can reach the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<a href="/passengers/">` it will send you to something like: `http://localhost:8080/passengers/`.

That's not what you want. You want `http://localhost:8080/AirlineDB_Spring/passengers/`

So, either you use `<a href="/AirlineDB_Spring/passengers/">` 
or you use that: `<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/passengers/">` the second option is a better pratice.

Also, it's good for you to add a mapping value to your RequestMapping. Try to use as follow:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {
        List<String> tl = new ArrayList<String>();
        tl.add("one");
        tl.add("two");
        tl.add("three");
        model.addAttribute("testlist", tl);
        return "mainview";
    }
```

Add the value="/" to your @RequestMapping.

Answer (score 1):

Either of this should work. You could use index method which is the default mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {
        // ...
    }
```

Or instead `list` rename to `index` as follows

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String index(Model model) {
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: I tried your advice, both of them, but I still get the same 404 error. Should I call the Controller a different way? because the url I get when I call it, seems strange, it doesn't contain the project name as the other urls of jsp-s

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first slash in

```
<a href="/passengers/">click</a>
```

makes it an absolute path. Will it work if you remove it?